# Having trouble sending create account data from React to Flask endpoint

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

Im trying to work on my Register component in my web app project. So far I was able to render this page, but now the biggest issue I'm facing is trying to submit the form to send the data to my Flask backend. Im not sure why its not working and Im completely stumped. Im new to React so figuring out all this is new for me.

One thing I noticed is that, I have Flask running on port 5000, but when I run React it runs on port 3000. Could this be an issue? If so, how would I fix this?

```
 ***React***
import React, {Component, useState} from "react";


function Register () {

    const [inputF_name, setInputF_name] = useState("");
    const [inputL_name, setInputL_name] = useState("");
    const [inputUsername, setInputUsername] = useState("");
    const [inputEmail, setInputEmail] = useState("");
    const [inputPassword, setInputPassword] = useState("");
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("http://localhost:5000/register")
    const [response, setResponse] = useState("")

    const registerAccount = async () => {
      const output = document.getElementById("flaskResponse");
      const configs = {
        method : "POST",
        mode : "cors",
        headers : {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
        body : JSON.stringify({
          f_name : inputF_name,
          l_name : inputL_name,
          username : inputUsername,
          email : inputEmail,
          password : inputPassword
        })
      }
      try {
        JSON.parse(configs);
        const response = await fetch(url, configs);
        const flaskResponse = await response.json();
        setResponse(flaskResponse["response"]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      output.innerHTML += "<p>" + response + "</p>";
    }
    return (
      <div className="Register">

        <h2>Register Account</h2>
        <div id="flaskResponse"/>
       <center><form className = "registerForm">
        <input
          type = "text" 
          id="f_name" 
          onChange={e => setInputF_name(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="First Name">
        </input>
        <br></br>
        <input
          type = "text"  
          id="l_name" 
          onChange={e => setInputL_name(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Last Name">
        </input>
        <br></br>
        <input 
          type = "text"
          id="username" 
          onChange={e => setInputUsername(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Username">
        </input>
        <br></br>
        <input 
          type = "password"
          id="password" 
          onChange={e => setInputPassword(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Password">
        </input>
        <br></br>
        <input 
          type = "text"
          id="email" 
          onChange={e => setInputEmail(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Email">
        </input>

      </form></center> 
        <br></br>
        <center>
        <button onClick={() => registerAccount()} id="registerButton">Register</button>
        </center>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default Register;
```

---

---

```
 ***FLASK***
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session, jsonify, flash, url_for
from backend_app.user import User
from flask_cors import CORS

dbpath = "./data/transit.db"

app = Flask(name)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/register', methods = ["POST"])
def register():

    error_message = "There was an error creating your account! Please try again."
    data = request.get_json()

    f_name = data['f_name']
    l_name = data['l_name']
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    email = data['email']

    encrypted_password = encrypt_password(password)

    new_user = User(pk = None, username = username, encrypted_password = encrypted_password, f_name = f_name, l_name = l_name, balance = balance)

    try:
        new_user.save()
        print("Thanks for joining Transit Buddy!", new_user.username)
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
        return jsonify({"error": error_message})
    finally: 
        #should return user to loggedin screen
        return redirect("/homepage")
if name == "main":
    app.run(debug=True, port = 5000)
```

Comment: did you checked network tab in browser did React dispatch the call at all? also why do you do JSON.parse(configs); you don't need that line at all.

Comment: @vaske Yeahh all I'm seeing 200 Get requests but then I see a 400 on my POST request for submitting the create account form. But im trying to figure out why thats happening. As for the JSON.parse(configs) thing. I was looking a few stackoverflow things and some people said it worked for them. Didn't for me though lol

Comment: also it should be const parsedConfig = JSON.parse(configs);

Comment: @vaske thanks for keeping up with this! Was actually able to figure it out but somewhat stuck on another problem which I'll make another post about